# two different size of datasets filtering using timestamp or intersection?

Tags: matlab, timestamp, dataset, intersection

I have two datasets vectors X = [TimeStamp1 a] and Y = [TimeStamp2 b]. I want to select only those data points of 'a' and 'b' whose reading matching with their timestamp1 and TimeStamp2 are matching. I tried to do this with 'ismember'. In short I want to select only those values of 'a' and 'b' which giving reading in same time Stamp. I was thinking to use 'intersect' so that I can select only those values whose timestamp is matching and if there is a mismatch in timestamp they must not include that data in my final datasets. I wondering How can I use this one in matlab. I have given below a reading of two datasets values. Note Time Stamps in both have 10 min of average data so I want only those reading which have 10 min of average in both datasets. There may be some reading of of record of say 5 min average which final data sets must exclude and datasets are not in same size so I want to select only those datasets values which can record upto same size values only. I attached the image file of my two datasets please have a look and kindly help me on this prob.... Thanks in advance :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip39s.png)

Comment: Can you share your code and an example?

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty straightforward to be accomplished.
Assuming that your two datasets are well structured, each timestamp will correspond to a certain index in both matrixes.

Therefore, you just need to go and compare the timestamps and save the corresponding indexes in both matrixes. That way you are able to know the exact moments in both matrixes.

Comment: could you demonstrate with simple matlab example ,..?? I tried to use indexes but made but I made some mistake ??  I think I can use intersection where when ever two datasets values are having common values or overlapping then it would make me final value